# How to change control schemes?

Tags: unity, input

I have been experimenting with Unity's new input system, but one thing I don't understand and couldn't find the answer for is how you change between control schemes.

Basically, I want my game to support multiple devices, but only support one device at a time, which is of course changeable in the settings menu. What code would I use to switch between a control scheme for, say, keyboards, and one for controllers?

Comment: For most purposes, you don't need to manually change between control schemes in an options menu. You can set up the actions in your map to be activated by *either* the keyboard key or the corresponding gamepad, within a single control scheme. Whichever one the player interacts with will take control automatically. Do you have a use case for which this automatic selection is not suitable? If so, it would help if you edit your question to explain that situation in detail, along with how you've configured your action maps so far.

Comment: @DMGregory: I can't speak for the OP, but I was looking at Control Schemes in part so that the UI reflected the correct names for the controls.